# Jest testing without service connecting to DB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, testing, mongoose, jestjs

I am having issues with testing my nodejs app that has multiple connections to the DB.

I would like to run my test without creating any connections to the DB. However, since the individual connections are required in my model, it seems to be connecting to the DB even though it is not needed.

I am using jest with supertest for testing.

/mongodbConnection

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { MONGO_URI1, MONGO_URI2 } = require('../config');

const db1Connection = mongoose.createConnection(MONGO_URI1, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
});

const db2Connection = mongoose.createConnection(MONGO_URI2, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
});;

module.exports = {
  db1Connection,
  db2Connection,
};
```

/student.model

```
const { Schema, model } = require('mongoose');
const { db1Connection } = require('../mongodbConnection');

const studentSchema = new Schema(
  {
    studentId: { type: Number, required: true },
    email: { type: String, required: true },
    profileImage: { type: String, required: true },
  },
  {
    collection: 'students',
    timestamps: { updatedAt: 'lastModifiedTimeStamp' },
  }
);

module.exports = db1Connection.model('StudentSchema', studentSchema);
```

/service

```
const Student = require('../models/student.model');
const getStudent = async (params) => {
  try {
    let student = await Student.findOne({ ...params })
      .exec();
    return student;
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error('Cannot find student');
  }
};
```

test.js

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const request = require('supertest');

const { getStudentInfo } = require('../getStudent.controller');

const { getStudent } = require('../student.service');

// mock service
jest.mock('../student.service');

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use('/student', getStudentInfo);

describe('GET student controller', () => {

  const mockData = [
    {
      studentId: 'abc',
      email: 'test@test.com',
      profileImage: 'test.jpg',
    },
  ];

  getStudent.mockResolvedValue(mockData);

  describe('GET /student', () => {
    it('Responds with correct student', async (done) => {
      const response = await request(app).get('/student');

      expect(response.status).toBe(200);
      expect(response.body).toEqual({ student: mockData });
      return done();
    });
  });

});
```

So when I test the controller and mock the service, the error shows up that there is a need to connect to DB. However, I do not require that in my controller testing as I have mocked the service. So is there any way I can overcome this?

The tests works if i only make a single connection using mongoose.connect. However when I use the above code, it breaks the tests and asks for the env variables.

Comment: can you post the error here

Comment: The error just says there Is no env variable provided. However, I don’t need the connection for testing

Comment: can you add the test code and the function that you want to mock in service, else you can mock the model function and make sure the jest.config file has `testEnvironment: "node"`

Comment: hmm how do i mock the model function?

Comment: Updated with test code

Answer (score 0):

```
const Student = require('../models/student.model');
const mock = jest.spyOn(Student, 'findOne');
const mockData = [
 {
  studentId: 'abc',
  email: 'test@test.com',
  profileImage: 'test.jpg',
 },
];
mock.mockImplementation(() => {
   return {
     populate: ()=>{
       return {
         exec: () => Promise.resolve(mockData)
       }
     }
    }
 });
```

Comment: What does spyOn do?

Comment: By default, jest.spyOn also calls the spied method. This is different behavior from most other test libraries. If you want to overwrite the original function, you can use jest.spyOn(object, methodName).mockImplementation(() => customImplementation)